# How to keep the original image format when inserted into a CRichEditCtrl?

Tags: c++, mfc

I used the COleRichEditCtrl class in this page http://www.codeproject.com/KB/edit/COleRichEditCtrl.aspx
So I can insert an image into the CRichEditCtrl using copy & paste.
However, it appears that it will automatically convert the image into an uncompressed WMF format when i paste the image. As a result, when I copy a JPG of size 500KB and paste it into the control, then use StreamOut() to store the content into a .rtf file, the file size will be as large as 6MB!! This is certainly unacceptable. So is there a way to keep the original format of the image so the size doesn't boost? Many many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Whatever you copy and paste in the RichEdit control, while saving that file, it always convert the content into RTF format. If you only link the image file, the size of your document will be very small. But if you embed it in your document, the size will increase. There is no other option.